# Need to set off an sound after 10 seconds in a python project

Tags: python

I am currently trying the driver drowsiness detection project using python and until now it can detect the drowsiness, I want to play a sound after 10 seconds if it continuously shows drowsy.
How can I program it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

At the first time the condition becomes true, start a performance timer. Once the condition is false, set `start` to False. If the performance timer reaches 10 seconds, play the sound. Might look something like this:

```py
import time

start = False
while True:
    if condition and not start:
        start = time.perf_counter()
    if not condition:
        start = False

    if start > 10:
        start = False
        playsound("my_sound.mp3", block=False)
```

Comment: Thank you ❤Can i get your mail ID if i have any other questions 

Comment: @primevishnu you can add me on discord @Anonymous4045#5005